# How to use 2 forms in 1 twig in Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, twig

Im have 2 entities: **Post** and **Article**. In my **TestController** i have a function named: **addAction()** where im trying to get these 2 entities and add them some data, but when i'm trying to do this when i run my app, the forms are submited succesfully, but the 2 tables (posts and articles) are empty. Why ?

Here's my addAction function:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $article = new Article();

        $postForm = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $articleForm = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);

        $postForm->handleRequest($request);
        $articleForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($postForm->isValid() && $articleForm->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($post);
            $em->persist($article);

            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->render('add/add.html.twig', array(
            'postForm' => $postForm->createView(),
            'articleForm' => $articleForm->createView()
        ));
    }
```

And the twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Add Post</h1>
            {{ form_start(postForm) }}
                {{ form_widget(postForm) }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Post <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            {{ form_end(postForm) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Add Article</h1>
            {{ form_start(articleForm) }}
            {{ form_widget(articleForm) }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Article <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
            {{ form_end(articleForm) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: First problem that I see is that submiting one form on a page that holds 2 forms will result sending the data only for that submited form - not for both.

Comment: How the problem can be solved ?

Comment: Try to see if you can create one form for both entities. I don't really know the result of handleRequest() if you're going to use 2 of them in one form (if it knows how to allocate the fields to entities).

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: You can render controller in twig http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html. It is the easiest solution

Comment: Use one form.  Make yourself a PostArticleType, pass it ['post'=$post,'article'=$article] and then add PostType and ArticleType Quite a common requirement.  Stackoverflow has plenty of more detailed examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't submit two forms simultaneously. So, instead, submit them one by one

```
$postForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($postForm->isSubmitted() && $postForm->isValid()) {
    // persist and flush $post
}

$articleForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($articleForm->isSubmitted() && $articleForm->isValid()) {
    // persist and flush $article
}
```